# Raycast for melee hitbox system not working properly

Tags: lua, roblox

I have a roblox raycast hitbox for my combat system and i just cannot attack players from back it is just impossible to attack players from back but you can attack from front. Btw you can attack NPCs from back and front

here is the code

```lua
game.ReplicatedStorage.M1Combat.Remotes.C1.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr)

    warn("Attack1Triggered")
    plr.Character:WaitForChild("stunned").Value = true
    wait(0.1)

    local punchPosition = plr.Character.HumanoidRootPart.Position
    local punchDirection = plr.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame.LookVector
    local punchLength = 8
    local offsetMagnitude = -3 -- Adjust the offset magnitude as needed
    script.Swing:Play()

    -- Calculate the starting position of the ray
    local offsetVector = punchDirection * offsetMagnitude
    local rayStart = punchPosition + offsetVector

    -- Create a ray from the calculated starting position and direction
    local ray = Ray.new(rayStart, punchDirection * punchLength)

    -- Create an IgnoreList to exclude parts belonging to the player
    local ignoreList = {}
    for _, characterPart in pairs(plr.Character:GetDescendants()) do
        if characterPart:IsA("BasePart") then
            table.insert(ignoreList, characterPart)
        end
    end

    -- Perform the raycast and get the first intersecting part
    local hitPart, hitPosition = workspace:FindPartOnRayWithIgnoreList(ray, ignoreList, false, true)

    if hitPart then
        if hitPart.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") and hitPart.Parent.Name ~= plr.Name and not dbz then
            dbz = true

             --Check if the hit part has the "Block" attribute
            --if hitPart:FindFirstChild("sus") then
            --  script.Swing:Stop()
            --  script["Block Sound Effect"]:Play()
            --  local Slash = game.ReplicatedStorage.BlockedSign:Clone()
            --  Slash.Parent = workspace
            --  Slash.Name = plr.Name .. Slash.Name
            --  Slash.CanCollide = false
            --  Slash.Anchored = true
            --  Slash.CFrame = hitPart.Parent.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame * CFrame.new(0, math.random(-3,0.5), math.random(-2.3, -1.0)) * CFrame.Angles(math.rad(0), math.rad(0), math.rad(0))
            --  print("Blocked by part with 'Block' attribute")
            --  wait(0.2)
            --  Slash:Destroy()
            --else
                
            --  script.Swing:Stop()
            --      script.Punch1:Play()

                    
            --      print("Damage dealt to the player")
            --      if hitPart.Parent:FindFirstChild("stunned").Value == false then
            --          hitPart.Parent:FindFirstChild("stunned").Value = true
            --          task.wait(1.5)
            --          hitPart.Parent:FindFirstChild("stunned").Value = false
            --      end
            --      hitPart.Parent.Humanoid:TakeDamage(3)
            
                
            --end
            
            
            
            if hitPart:FindFirstChild("sus") then
                script.Swing:Stop()
                script["Block Sound Effect"]:Play()
                local Slash = game.ReplicatedStorage.BlockedSign:Clone()
                Slash.Parent = workspace
                Slash.Name = plr.Name .. Slash.Name
                Slash.CanCollide = false
                Slash.Anchored = true
                Slash.CFrame = hitPart.Parent.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame * CFrame.new(0, math.random(-3, 0.5), math.random(-2.3, -1.0)) * CFrame.Angles(math.rad(0), math.rad(0), math.rad(0))
                print("Blocked by part with 'Block' attribute")
                wait(0.2)
                Slash:Destroy()
            else
                
                coroutine.wrap(function()
                    
                        hitPart.Parent:FindFirstChild("stunned").Value = true
                        wait(1.5)
                        hitPart.Parent:FindFirstChild("stunned").Value = false

                end)()
                
                script.Swing:Stop()
                script.Punch1:Play()

                
                print("Damage dealt to the player")

                -- Use a coroutine to wait without blocking the rest of the script
                
                hitPart.Parent.Humanoid:TakeDamage(3)
            end

            
            

            wait(0.11)
            dbz = false
        end
    end

    wait(1)
    if plr.Character:WaitForChild("stunned").Value == true then
        plr.Character:WaitForChild("stunned").Value = false
    end
    warn("C1 end")
end)
```

This is the first combo of the combat.